# How does dotnet build generate app.runtimeconfig.json internally?

Tags: .net, .net-core, msbuild

I would like to generate `app.runtimeconfig.json` file but *without* using `dotnet build`. What program and flags as part of the .NET SDK do I need to run in order to generate this file?

The file might look like this:

```json
{
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "tfm": "net5.0",
    "framework": {
      "name": "Microsoft.NETCore.App",
      "version": "5.0.0"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: From [`runtimeconfig.json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/run-time-config/#runtimeconfigjson) _If a `runtimeconfig.template.json` file exists in the same folder as the project file, any configuration options it contains are inserted into the `[appname].runtimeconfig.json`_ _

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the SDK has built-in means to do what you are asking for.

The thing that generates it is the [GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/blob/master/src/Tasks/Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks/GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles.cs) msbuild task which is used by the SDK's `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets` and `Microsoft.NET.Publish.targets` when building or publishing you project. You can configure it in your csproj:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>true</GenerateRuntimeConfigurationFiles>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puting tag below in your csproj file could help sometimes.

```
<EnableDynamicLoading>true</EnableDynamicLoading>
```